# Count occurrences of an element in a list

Tags: f#

I have a list of integers and any integers that occur multiple times will do so consecutively. I would like to convert this to a list of tuples, containing each object together with its count.

I have come up with the below, but there is a problem with the return type of temp: "The type 'int' does not match the type ''a list'". However, the three return types look consistent to me. What have I done wrong? If what I've done is not good F# and should be done in a completely different way, please also let me know.

```
let countoccurences list =
    match list with
    | x::xs -> let rec temp list collecting counted =
                    match list with
                    | x::xs when x=collecting -> temp xs collecting counted+1
                    | x::xs -> (collecting,counted)::temp xs x 1
                    | [] -> (collecting,counted)::[]
               temp xs x 1
    | [] -> []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
| x::xs when x=collecting -> temp xs collecting counted+1
```

the compiler interprets your code as

```
| x::xs when x=collecting -> (temp xs collecting counted)+1
```

but what you want is

```
| x::xs when x=collecting -> temp xs collecting (counted+1)
```

However, even with this change, one problem with your algorithm is that the `temp` function is not tail-recursive, which means that it can cause a stack overflow when called on a long list (e.g. `countoccurences [1..10000]` fails on my machine).  If this is important to you, then you should rewrite your `temp` helper function to be tail recursive.  The easiest way to do this is to add an accumulated list parameter and reverse the list afterwards.

```
let countoccurences list =
    match list with
    | x::xs -> 
        let rec temp list collecting counted acc =
            match list with
            | x::xs when x = collecting -> temp xs collecting (counted+1) acc
            | x::xs -> temp xs x 1 ((collecting, counted)::acc)
            | [] -> (collecting, counted)::acc
        temp xs x 1 []
        |> List.rev
    | [] -> []
```

Answer (score 29):

EDIT: Oops, this does not answer your question, since you said "consecutive".  But I'll leave it here since someone searching the question title may find it useful.

`Seq.countBy` does this.

```
let list = [1;2;3;4;5;6;1;2;3;1;1;2]
let results = list |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.toList 
printfn "%A" results
// [(1, 4); (2, 3); (3, 2); (4, 1); (5, 1); (6, 1)]
```

Comment: I like this. Though i do not like the tupled result. Is there a way to make it return only integers? Say I am so lucky that that i can identify the results by the index value of the list.

Comment: what's `id` here?

Answer (score 9):

What about this one?

```
lst |> Seq.groupBy (fun x -> x) |> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> (a, Seq.length(b)))
```

Comment: `(fun x -> x)` can be spelled `id`

Comment: Not sure why this has more up-votes than @Brian's answer. `countBy` does exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Daniel voting is all about human behavior and not correctness.

Comment: @gradbot - I thought it was worth pointing out to future visitors that there's a built-in solution.

Comment: TBH @Brian's solution might be shorter and simpler, but to me this solution is more readable

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a mutable solution for this. Maybe something like:

```
let countOccurrences l =
    let counts = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary()
    l |> List.iter (fun x -> 
        match counts.TryGetValue(x) with
        | true, i -> counts.[x] <- i + 1
        | _ -> counts.Add(x, 1))
    counts |> Seq.map (|KeyValue|)
```

**EDIT**

I forgot about `countBy` (which is implemented similarly).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using recursion to traverse a list, you can always use fold.

```
let countOccurrences = function
| []    -> []
| x::xs -> ([(x,1)],xs)
           ||> List.fold(fun ((y,c)::acc) x -> if x = y then (y,c+1)::acc else (x,1)::(y,c)::acc) 
           |> List.rev
```